# Como povoar historico no ionic framework

Tags: mobile, ionic

Bom estou precisando saber como povoar o histórico do `ionic framework`, do próprio `window` eu sei que é assim:

```
 window.history.pushState({upage:sel}, sel, document.location.origin + document.location.pathname +sel);
```

O meu problema que estou precisando gravar o historio "nome" das paginas em que eu passei para ao clica no botão voltar nativo ele deve volta a visão anterior, desta forma utilizando o método de voltar do `window` ele volta apenas um visão.